# Android User Session

Tags: java, android, session, authentication

i'am just learning about Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/but how to make a session function so i can make in my home screen(dashboard.xml) the name who login. like welcome "the name of user who get login". i'am still beginner for android, thank you so much for your help.

this is my loginactivity.java

```
package unai.skripsi.nexttry;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import unai.skripsi.nexttry.entity.DatabaseHandler;
import unai.skripsi.nexttry.entity.UserFunctions;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
Button btnLogin;
Button btnLinkToRegister;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView loginErrorMsg;


// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();  


            new MyAsyncTask().execute(email, password);
        }

            // check for login response
        class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                    if (params.length != 2)
                            return null;
                    JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(params[0], params[1]);
                    return json;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                    try {
                if (json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new   DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }}
    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
   }
}
```

this is my Registeractivity.java

```
package unai.skripsi.nexttry;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import unai.skripsi.nexttry.entity.DatabaseHandler;
import unai.skripsi.nexttry.entity.UserFunctions;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
Button btnRegister;
Button btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

    // Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            new MyAsyncTask().execute(name, email, password);
        }

            // check for login response
        class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                    if (params.length != 3)
                            return null;
                    JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(params[0], params[1], params[2]);
                    return json;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                    // check for login response
            try {
                if (json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully registred
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        
                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in registration
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }}
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Close Registration View
            finish();
        }
    });
   }
 }
```

this is my DashboardActivity.java

```
package unai.skripsi.nexttry;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import unai.skripsi.nexttry.library.UserFunctions;

public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {
UserFunctions userFunctions;
Button btnLogout;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /**
     * Dashboard Screen for the application
     * */       
    // Check login status in database
    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){
   // user already logged in show databoard
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(login);
                // Closing dashboard screen
                finish();
            }
        });

    }else{
        // user is not logged in show login screen
        Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(login);
        // Closing dashboard screen
        finish();
    }        
 }
}
```

this is my login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#3b3b3b" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >
    <!--  View Title Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <!--  Email Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email" />
    <!--  Email TextField -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!--  Password Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="Password" />
    <!--  Password TextField -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:password="true" />

    <!--  Error message -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/login_error"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#e30000"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!--  Login Button -->       
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="Login" />

    <!--  Link to Registration Screen -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLinkToRegisterScreen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="I don&apos;t have account. Register Me!"
        android:textColor="#21dbd4"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

this is my register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#3b3b3b" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >
    <!--  View Title Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <!--  Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Full Name" />
    <!--  Name TextField -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/registerName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!--  Email Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email" />
    <!--  Email TextField -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/registerEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!--  Password Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="Password" />
    <!--  Password TextField -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/registerPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:password="true" />

    <!--  Error message -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/register_error"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#e30000"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!--  Login Button -->       
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="Register" />

    <!--  Link to Login Screen -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLinkToLoginScreen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Already registred. Login Me!"
        android:textColor="#21dbd4"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

this is my dashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#3b3b3b">

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="WELCOME"
          android:textSize="40dip"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_marginTop="20dip"/>

<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Logout Me"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textColor="#21dbd4"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
    android:background="@null"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) in my opinion,

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) is also a good resource for learning about the different storage options